# Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare() on theme functions

Tags: php, wordpress

I upgraded my old site from wordpress version 3.4 to 4.4 recently. Suddenly I am getting a PHP warning as per below:

Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in ...../wp-content/themes/...functions/admin-functions.php on line 1543 and defined in .......public/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1246

Below are the codes for **admin-functions.php**:

```
global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT *,count(*) AS used FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_page_template' AND meta_value = '$filename' GROUP BY meta_value";

    $results = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare($query),'ARRAY_A'); // Select thrid coloumn accross


    if(empty($results))

        return false;
```

and **wp-db.php**

```
public function prepare( $query, $args ) {
    if ( is_null( $query ) )
        return;
```

Comment: When calling ``$wpdb->prepare($query)`` you pass a single argument (``$query``) while ``prepare( $query, $args )`` takes two arguments...

Comment: @Kraal - two **or more**  arguments....

Comment: indeed "at least" two

Comment: **Important:** Did you build this theme, or is this a purchased / off-the-shelf theme? If it's an off-the-shelf theme, you should contact them theme developer....

Comment: Thanks for all your help. 

This code is from a child theme that was created by a freelance developer who is unreachable now. Do you know if this error is caused by his sub-par coding, or due to recent changes in Wordpress or PHP standards/methods that require such outdated code to be updated? 

For now, we are thinking of changing to a new theme that is compatible with the latest version of Wordpress - would this be a good solution, rather than trying to fix the current theme that has this, and potentially other issues?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use placeholders and add the variable as an argument to prepare,`%s` is a placeholder for string value,assuming it is string from your quotes

```
$query = "SELECT *,count(*) AS used FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
     WHERE meta_key = '_wp_page_template' AND meta_value = %s 
         GROUP BY meta_value";

    $results = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare($query,$filename),'ARRAY_A'); // Select thrid coloumn accross
```

Comment: This is a quick and dirty solution to the **current** issue, but would be good to link to docs and / or explain the different placeholders, etc. (%s, %d)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading the documentation for [$wpdb->prepare](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/).

Prepare requires at least two arguments to be passed in.  The first is the query, using placeholders (`%s` for a string and `%d` for a number), and the second is the list of variables / values to place into the query instead of the placeholders.

For your specific case, I'm demonstrating in a bit longer format so you can see clearly:

```
global $wpdb;

// Old query.  Let's get it ready for prepare...
// $query = "SELECT *,count(*) AS used FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_page_template' AND meta_value = '$filename' GROUP BY meta_value";

// New query, ready for prepare:
$query = "SELECT *,count(*) AS used FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s AND meta_value = %s GROUP BY meta_value";

// Now we pass that into prepare, along with the two values we want replaced
$wpdb->prepare($query, '_wp_page_template', $filename);

// And we execute the query...
$results = $wpdb->get_row($query,'ARRAY_A');
```

Note that you can use the placeholders for as many values as you want, but the idea is that you use them for **any value that is user input**.  If the value may be posted through a form, for example, you absolutely want to use prepare on that value.  Example:

```
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
$query = 'SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id = %d';
$query = $wpdb->prepare($query, $post_id);
```

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass $meta_key as second argument.

eg:-

```
<?php
// set the meta_key to the appropriate custom field meta key
$meta_key = 'miles';
$allmiles = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        SELECT sum(meta_value) 
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
        WHERE meta_key = %s
    ", 
    $meta_key
) );
echo "<p>Total miles is {$allmiles}</p>";
?>
```

so here your second second argument is $filename.

Reference :- [Class Reference / wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)